# Programmatically start systemd service or test if service running

Tags: linux, systemd

I need to start a service and (later) detect if it running from within a C++ program.  Is there a simpler approach than invoking systemctl with suitable arguments and parsing the output?

The source of the service is entirely under my control.  (Currently it is written in bash, but a C++ wrapper is entirely possible.)

(I've had a brief look at DBus - it is clearly very powerful, but fails the "simpler" test.)

The source of the service is entirely under my control.  (Currently it is written in bash, but C++ is entirely possible.)

The code is for an embedded device running a variant of Debian Jessie.  Portability is not a major concern (but obviously the answer will be more useful to others if it is portable).

Comment: Why do you need to detect if the service is still running? When and why would that service stop running? What exact service are you talking about?

Comment: The main program is itself a service which can auto-update.  Obviously the update procedure involves restarting the main service.  By creating the update process as a separate (one-shot) service, it is in a separate cgroup, and doesn't get killed by killing the main service.  When the main service starts and finds that we are in UPDATE mode, it wants to know if the update service is still running or if it has crashed.

Comment: That still does not tell us what is your mysterious service serving.... And you should **edit your question**, not comment it!

Comment: From within `ttm.service`, I want to detect if `ttm.update.service` is running or if it has finished.  The purpose of `ttm.update.service` is to, er, update `ttm.service` :-)  Is that clearer?

Comment: Why not let your OS' service manager worry about keeping the service up, then query its status with `service`/`status` or other init.d scripts (e.g. cron)? Separation of concerns and all that.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: What do you mean by "query its status with `service / status`?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: I don't want to "keep it up".  It's a one-shot service that will update my main service and then exit.  I want to know whether it has finished or not.

Comment: On Debian, you can control daemons via [`service`](https://wiki.debian.org/Daemon#Common_daemon_controls).

Comment: Except that my daemon(s) are defined by unit files in `/etc/systemd/system`, and not scripts in `/etc/init.d` - so `service` doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Most programs are written with the other way in mind (even in pre-systemd days).

Typical services (those having and started with a *single* server process) are writing their PID (as an ASCII number on a single line) in some `/var/run/foobar.pid` file at their startup. If you adopt such a convention in your service, you can read that file using `fscanf` then check that the process is running with `kill(`*pid*`, 0);` (of course, you cannot be certain that it is the same service, but it probably would be).

I have right now more than 20 files matching `/var/run/*.pid`, notably `/var/run/sshd.pid` & `/var/run/atd.pid`

So, assuming you can improve the code of your service *FooBar* (if that functionality is not there), change its code to write its pid into `/var/run/foobar.pid`; this is a documented [convention](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html).

If you can change the service, you might have it providing some *ping* or *nop* functionality; so you would add to it some RPC facility which justs check that the service is running (and could also give some additional information, like the version of the program, etc.). Most existing Linux services have such feature.

Comment: 1. Doesn't solve the "start service" part (but invoking systemctl is easy enough for that).  2.  I don't like PID files in principle.  They prove that the process started, the `kill(`pid`, 0);` test proves that a process with that PID is running ... but it doesn't prove it is the *same* process (and there are only 32767 unique PIDs on my Linux). OTOH, it is probably the best I can do :-(

Answer (score 0):

Why not flip the problem around?  No parsing would be needed.

`ttm.update.service` will do the following.

```
systemctl stop ttm.service
systemctl disable ttm.service
#do you update here
#if the service configs changed do
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable ttm.service
systemctl start ttm.service
```

`ttm.service` would never have to worry about the `updater`, it just runs and do it's job.